# PHP redirect based on HTTP_HOST/SERVER_NAME within same domain

Tags: php, redirect, dns

I am trying to redirect to a specific path based on HTTP_HOST or SERVER_NAME with a PHP-script.

I have tried these scripts:

1.

```
$domain = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
if (($domain == "example.dk") ||
   ($domain == "www.example.dk")) { 
   header("location: /index.php/da/forside"); 
}
?>
```

2.

```
switch ($host) {

        case 'example.dk':
                header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                header("Location: http://www.example.dk/index.php/da/forside/");
                exit();

        case 'www.example.dk':
                header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
                header("Location: http://www.example.dk/index.php/da/forside/");
                exit();



        default:
                header("Location: http://www.example.se");
                exit();

                }
?>
```

And other similar scripts. Either the page loads forever or the browser returns some redirection error.

Comment: What is the initial URL you open?

Comment: Just for your info, in your first example, the location must be a fully qualified URL and not a relative path.

Comment: @Nirmal same problem whether it's relative or absolute URL

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, this is how I solved it:

```
<?php
$domain = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
$requri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (($domain == "www.example.dk" && $requri == "/index.php"  ||
   $domain == "example.dk") )  { 
   Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
   header("location: http://www.example.dk/index.php/da/forside"); 
}

else if (($domain == "uk.example.dk" && $requri == "/index.php"  ||
   $domain == "www.uk.example.dk") )  {
   Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" );    
   header("location: http://uk.example.dk/index.php/en/uk/home"); 
}

else if (($domain == "www.example.se" && $requri == "/index.php"  ||
   $domain == "example.se") )  { 
   Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
   header("location: http://example.se/index.php/sv/hem"); 
}

?>
```

It appears I need the REQUEST_URI field, otherwise it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The most common redirection error is a redirection loop.

1. Does the script really end after your first example?
2. Where does $host come from?

Also, SERVER_NAME is usually an apache configured global name, HTTP_HOST is really the right way to do this.

HTTP_HOST may contain the port number, keep this in mind.

So what's the url of your script, and where are you redirecting to?

A simple way to debug is to echo the contents of HTTP_HOST and instead of calling header(), also call 'echo'.

Answer (score 0):

Because your are redirecting to the same server (example.dk) and your code executes again and again in a loop.

use this code instead:

```
$domain = $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
if (($domain == "example.dk" ||
   $domain == "www.example.dk") && !$_GET['redirected'])  { 
   header("location: /index.php/da/forside?redirected=1"); 
}
```

Comment: **The PHP Documentation says:** `HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs.` So it's better to have an absolute URI in your example.

Comment: It worked, but when I click on anything on that page, I can't surf nowhere. I am just stuck on that page. Also, will this be search engine friendly?

Comment: @nctrnl what are your other pages urls?

Comment: @rahim asgari like this: http://example.dk/index.php/da/axe, http://example.dk/index.php/da/sword, etc

Comment: they are in example.dk domain too. so they will redirect to /index.php/da/forside too.

Comment: Is it possible to make like "ends with example.dk", so that it doesn't make this redirect thingy when I'm trying to visit links on the same domain?